# Can Subversion be configured for Windows Authentication without Apache

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2003, windows-authentication

I've setup Subversion following Jeff Atwood's article at [Coding Horror: Setting up Subversion on Windows](https://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/). I followed the steps exactly and I have SVNSERVE now running as a service on a Windows 2003 server in our LAN.

I've also installed TortoiseSVN and I've been playing with it and trying to learn more about it so I can spread the usage in our shop.

My question at this point is whether it is possible to somehow avoid use of the conf/passwd file where users and passwords are defined. I would hope to be able to use Windows authentication but from what I've gathered so far, Windows Authentication seems to be possible only with usage of Apache.

Is there a simple way to get Subversion configured to use Windows authentication without delving into Apache?

EDIT: I just discovered you have a sister site for stuff like this called serverfault.com. Should I post this question there (even though I am more of a developer than an administrator)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're after, but [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is a free package that the people at VisualSVN do. It's still using Apache under the hood, but as far as the simplistic administration goes - it's a client that does all the installation work for you (you just need this for your subversion server as it includes Subversion too).

This allows you to administrate your Windows Authentication setup via their admin app (which is a bit like a standard management app you might see for other databases). You can set users at Repository level, whether they have Read/Write permissions and overwrite them at any of the lower folder levels.

You do NOT need to use their client for Visual Studio (which is what they charge for), but they are hoping you do ;)

Again, it's not getting around the requirement for Apache - but it's abstracting it away so you have a little 'Black Box' methodology for your Subversion server. ;)

Comment: Thanks very much. I will look at this now. I had read about VisualSVN quickly and went away from it when I saw they charged for the product. I will look at the free package. Thanks again.

Comment: Hope it does what you want it to. It certainly works very well for me as much as it kerbed a little bit of the (fairly steep) learning curve. :)

Comment: Thing is, visualSVN server uses Apache. This is fine if you don't mind changing the server tech, and using the http protocol. But, the real question, is there a way of doing this *without* using apache?

Comment: @Jim Yep, I've mentioned in my reply that Apache is still being used. But my recommendation/answer was based on the fact John wanted to "avoid use of the conf/passwd file where users and passwords are defined". Agreed - the topic of the question asks about whether Apache can be replaced (and there is still scope for other answers to help with that), but I don't think that was the point of the question, maybe just a false starting point. (It's obviously not my question and my requirements, I just left my thoughts to what I perceived the problem to maybe be :) ).

Comment: Amadiere definitely got the "spirit" of my question (i.e. if indeed there is no way to do this without Apache (I think this has been confirmed), then eliminating the learning curve & maintenance chore(s) for Apache via use of this [free] package sounds pretty good to me. I shall be looking into the VisualSVN information today.